# Angular 5: Cannot insert a destroyed View into a ViewContainer

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting an error I've never seen before in my Angular app. The error is on [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L194) of the Angular source code.

This happens when I log out and log back in on my app. The route that I am on when doing that has an observable being observed, and as that emits a value to its stream, anything observing will update values and change detection will run, thus removing some elements and add some other elements.

I'm pretty sure the component below responsible for the error. Can anyone see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? I left in the parts that I think may be relevant to the bug and commented out everything else. Perhaps I'm improperly using `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ContentChild` here...

**Component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'paginated-infinite-scroll',
    templateUrl: './paginated-infinite-scroll.component.html'
})
export class PaginatedInfiniteScrollComponent {
    // ...

    @ContentChild('results') resultsRef: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ContentChild('noResults') noResultsRef: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ContentChild('loading') loadingRef: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ContentChild('loadingMore') loadingMoreRef: TemplateRef<any>;

    // ...
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300" [scrollWindow]="true" (scrolled)="scrolled()">
    <ng-container *ngIf="result.items.length > 0 && !loading">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="resultsRef"></ng-template>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="result.items.length === 0 && !loading">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="noResultsRef"></ng-template>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="loading">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="loadingRef"></ng-template>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="loadingMore">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="loadingMoreRef"></ng-template>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**Usage:**

```
<paginated-infinite-scroll [onScroll]="onScroll" [query]="query" [result]="result">
    <ng-template #results>
        // Loop through results here...
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #noResults>
        // Show no results message here...
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #loading>
        // Show loading spinner here...
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #loadingMore>
        // Show some other loading spinner here...
    </ng-template>
</paginated-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this. The bug was not actually coming from the code in my original question. I had an observable within a directive, and I was never unsubscribing. The directive was subscribing to an auth event, and every time I logged in/out it would try to either insert or detach the component it was attached to, and in this case since that component would be destroyed since I navigated away, the bug appeared.

This was my directive logic:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[loggedIn]'
})
export class LoggedInDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private which: boolean = false;
    private _loggedIn: boolean = false;

    view = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView(null);
    authEventsSub: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.authEventsSub = this.authEventsService.events$.subscribe((event: AuthEvent) => {
            this._loggedIn = (event === AuthEvent.LOGGED_IN) || (event === AuthEvent.READY);
            this.render();
        });
    }

    private render() {
        if (this.which) {
            if (this._loggedIn) {
                this.viewContainerRef.insert(this.view);
            } else {
                this.viewContainerRef.detach();
            }
        } else {
            if (this._loggedIn) {
                this.viewContainerRef.detach();
            } else {
                this.viewContainerRef.insert(this.view);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Fixed it by unsubscribing to the observable in the `ngOnDestroy` hook:

```
authEventsSub: Subscription;

constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private authEventsService: AuthEventsService,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.authEventsSub = this.authEventsService.events$.subscribe((event: AuthEvent) => {
        this._loggedIn = (event === AuthEvent.LOGGED_IN) || (event === AuthEvent.READY);
        this.render();
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.authEventsSub) {
        this.authEventsSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```